# How to center the navbar-brand in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I've tried a few things like using flex boxes auto margins and transforms etc but I can't seem to center this navbar-brand because it centers between the right hand side and a button and I want it to ignore the button and just center for the whole of the page using the page view port but i just can't get it to do it?

https://www.codeply.com/p/RXiaRJEqWj

**EDIT:**
Since my first version of this was closed before anyone else marks it as a duplicate please actually read the question as the solutions linked by ZIM don't work like stated in the first sentence of my question:

> I've tried a few things like using flex boxes auto margins and transforms etc but I can't seem to center this navbar-brand

Comment: Did you read the duplicates? Centering works exactly as explained in all the other answers: https://codeply.com/p/KtB1Ny1ENA

Comment: Also, please "the question must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"

Comment: Sorry if i didnt make it clear enough the first time i will change it to specify the viewport center now also Anis R. was able to provide the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about adding `position: absolute` to your button?

This will make the button not have its "reserved space" in the navbar anymore, which will let your target div be centered in the entire navbar.

Comment: Thank you i had tried a lot of things that just weren't working

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

To place the logo, center of the screen, we need to pull it left by 54px, which is the width of toggle button placed top left of the screen.

```
.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
   transform: translateX(-54px);
}
```

---

### Method 2

Make toggle button `absolute` positioning also works.

```
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
   position: absolute;
   top: 1rem;
   left: .5rem;
}
```

---